# How to prove this, $ | \Delta f | \leqslant n | \nabla^2 f| $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I hope to prove this,
$$ | \Delta f | \leqslant n | \nabla^2 f| $$
where $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R $.

Comment: -1 for unexplained notation in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
|\Delta f|=\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \partial_i^2 f\right|=
\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1\cdot\partial_i^2 f\right|\leq
\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\partial_i^2 f)^2\right)^{1/2}=
\sqrt{n}|\nabla^2 f|\leq n|\nabla^2 f| 
$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand.  Isn't $\Delta f=\nabla^2f$?
This is assuming that the first $\nabla$ means divergence, 
the second gradient.

Comment: oh sorry, $\Delta$ means laplacian.

Comment: @Miau The laplacian is defined as $\nabla^{2}$

Comment: Even if you define the Laplacian directly as the sum of the second partial derivatives, it is a very easy computation to show that $\Delta=\nabla^2$.

Comment: sorry, I wrote that $ \nabla^2 f = ( \partial_1^2 f , \cdots , \partial_n^2 f) $.

Comment: This is your definition of $\nabla^2$ now?  This is certainly not the usual definition.

Comment: Moreover, I'd probably write $\partial_{ii}^2$ for the second derivative with respect to the $i$-th variable.